# Use Realm Sync on UWP

Tags: uwp, realm

I would like to use realm sync on uwp project.

```
var realmUrl = new Uri("realm://52.230.25.125:9080/~/default");
var authURL = new Uri("http://52.230.25.125:9080");
var credentials = Credentials.UsernamePassword(username, password, createUser: false);
var user = await User.LoginAsync(credentials, authURL);
var config = new SyncConfiguration(user, realmUrl);
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
```

When I debug my project, await User.LoginAsync(credentials, authURL) never return me the user instance.

I got some warning message. "The referced component 'C\Users\me.nuget\packages\realm\2.1.0\build..\native\ios\universal\librealm-wrappers.a'" could not be found

Comment: That's because Realm Sync UWP was not supported until today, see the [official announcement](https://blog.realm.io/announcing-realm-dotnet/).

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#enabling-realm-platform

Comment: Can you share the versions of Realm Object Server and the .NET SDK that you're using?

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev My Realm Object Server is V1.8.3;  UWP SDK is v6.0.1

Comment: I was asking about the Realm SDK version. Also, do you get this in debug or release?

Comment: Nevermind, saw you are using 2.1.0 on the client. It's incompatible with ROS 1.x. You'll need to upgrade it to 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using an incompatible combination of the Realm SDK and Realm Object Server. You need to upgrade your ROS instance to 2.x.

Comment: I have upgrade my ROS to 2.0.18 Unfortunately, I got same problem